# How to get variable from within the function?

Tags: javascript, scope, google-visualization

I'm trying to access `myVariable` outside this function. Please see the code below:

```
var myVariable;
function drawBasic(){
...
  myVariable = document.getElementById('chart_div3');
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));


google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
        chart_div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';

        myVariable.innerHTML = chart.getImageURI();
        
        myVariable = myVariable.innerHTML;

        //prints out desired value
        console.log(myVariable);


});

//prints out desired value
console.log(myVariable);
...
}
//prints out undefined
    console.log(myVariable);
```

I know that `myVariable` is defined outside the function so I was hoping it could be set inside the function and then the value could be used anywhere else, but I was wrong. So my question would be how can I get the value of `chart.getImageURI()` and store it as a value outside the function `drawBasic`?

Comment: You were right, myVariable can be changed from inside the function. However, you've never assigned anything to it in any scope, so of course it remains `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because of a issue with your syntax in "***var =  myVariable***". I wrote this and it works fine.

```
var myVariable;
drawBasic();
function drawBasic(){
   myVariable = "Test String";
   //prints out desired value
   console.log(myVariable);
}
//prints out undefined
console.log(myVariable);
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/azstnqpv/)

Comment: Sorry this was my mistake, I have it as var myVariable and not var = myVariable.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your chart.getImageURI() in window.myVariable (always accessible) , or in a hidden form input, with jquery in your function :
$("#myHiddenItem").val(chart.getImageURI()) 
and where you need the value : 
$("#myHiddenItem").val()

Answer (score 0):

The reason your result is `undefined` is probably because of the order in which your code is executed: your last `console.log()` is called **after** drawBasic() is **defined**, but probably **before** drawBasic() is **executed**.

Inside the function, you can do:

```
myVariable = chart.getImageURI();
```

The value of the global (and therefore readable everywhere) variable myVariable will be set when the function is called.

After you execute drawBasic(), the value of myVariable should be correct, also when called outside the function.